# Fast application Autorun

Tags: windows-10, boot, start-screen

I'm using a Microsoft Surface 3 tablet (W10) for running a full-screen WPF application.

The application is now added in the "Startup" folder, and it takes a couple of seconds to launch after the OS boots up.

What I would like to do is to limit all the user input until my application loads, so they won't be able to access any Windows functionality.

The current approach isn't working, because until my app loads, there are a couple of seconds where users can do other stuff / don't know what to expect, or if anything is happening (desktop screen).

Any solutions?

Comment: You don't tell us what you want to prevent exactly. If you provide more specifics there might be a group policy you can enable/disable to prevent that action.  Of course what you want to use is indeed the built-in kiosk mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're attempting to achieve is called a *kiosk mode*.

Microsoft have [a guide on setting up Windows to run in kiosk mode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/set-up-a-kiosk-for-windows-10-for-desktop-editions) on their site. Basically, you have to use [Windows Configuration Designer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/provisioning-packages/provisioning-install-icd) which offers a *Provision kiosk devices* feature.

Please note that this feature is only available in Pro, Enterprise and Education editions of Windows. The basic Windows 10 dedicated for home users doesn't offer official kiosk mode.

Comment: I will point out that third-party Kiosk software doe exist.